# Unsupported UCS-4 endianness (3412) detected - Scala/Spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I was running a code on  spark/scala and I've got an error, which I don't know what means...

**Error : Caused by: java.io.CharConversionException: Unsupported UCS-4 endianness (3412) detected**

I imported some files and I was using the variable i stored it as parameter in a function, some files work, but there are some that don't.

Comment: This happened to me when reading a gzip compressed file as text file. If this is the case, adding the .gz file suffix or setting the compression code as gzip should solve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Yonatan Wilkof is right about the cause of this issue.

> This happened to me when reading a gzip compressed file as text file. If this is the case, adding the .gz file suffix or setting the compression code as gzip should solve the issue.

This code fixed the problem.

```
df = spark.read.format(file_format).load(file_path, header="true", compression="gzip")
```

--

My problem was a different one.

There was a problem with the encoding because the file_path contained a file other than a .gz file, for example, `.gz.__distcp__split_0.0`.

So I deleted the unformatted file and read it as shown below, and it read the gzip file fine without specifying any settings (because it automatically sets the codec).

```
df = spark.read.format(file_format).load(file_path, header="true")
```